# Repairing corrupted JPEG images from character replacement

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code, recover, repair

Recently I got some corrupted JPEG images after a mistakingly input command:

```
~$> sed -i 's/;/_/g' *
```

After that, in the working directory and the subdirectories, Every byte '0x3b' in JPEG images became '0x5f'. Viewer apps displays the images corrupted, such as below:
[corrupted image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdQpR.jpg)

I could not identify which byte should be recovered, and when I tried to validate the warning/error flags from the images with toolkits such as EXIFtool, they just returns OK as the corrupted JPEG is not literally *BROKEN* not to be opened by a viewer.

Images should be repaired, since there is no duplicated image backup for them, but I don't know how to start. Just replacing 0x5f with 0x3b again is not effective, since the number of cases would be too big (2^n I guess where there are n candidate 0x5f) to take the trial-and-error replacing way. I've just started parsing huffman table in a JPEG image header and hoping to identify the conflict point between huffman coded statement and binary, but not sure.

How can I recover the images in this situation? I appreciate your help.

Comment: "What would be your recommendation?" Restore from backup? Don't say scary stuff at the command line?

Comment: Pretty much hopeless. Your 2^n is correct, and the Huffman codes permit all sequences of bits. In fact, good compression should be able to produce almost all possible bit sequences. Otherwise it's not as good as it could be.

Answer (score -1):

There appear to be 57 incidences of `0x5f` in your corrupted image. If you can't find a better way, you could maybe *"eyeball"* the effects of replacing the incorrect bytes in the image fairly quickly like this:

- open the image in binary mode and read it all with `JPEG = open('PdQpR.jpg','rb').read()`
- use `offsets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(b'_', JPEG)]` to find the byte offsets of the 57 occurrences
- display the image with `cv2.imdecode()` and `cv2.imshow()` and then enter a loop accepting keypresses with `cv2.waitkey()`

  <kbd>p</kbd> = move to previous one of 57 occurrences

  <kbd>n</kbd> = move to next one of 57 occurrences

  <kbd>SPACE</kbd> = toggle between `0x5f` and `0x3b`

  <kbd>s</kbd> = save current state

  <kbd>q</kbd> = quit

I had a quick attempt at this but haven't had much success using it yet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import re
import numpy as np

# Load the image
filename = 'PdQpR.jpg'
JPEG = open(filename,'rb').read()
JPEG = bytearray(JPEG)

# Find the byte offsets of all the underscores
offsets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(b'_', JPEG)]
N = len(offsets)
index = 0

while True:
    # Show user which entry we are at
    print(f'{index}/{N}: n=next, p=previous, space=toggle, q=quit')
    # Decode and display the JPEG
    im = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow(filename, im)

    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    # n = next offset
    if key == ord('n'):
       index = (index + 1) % N
       next
    # p = previous offset
    if key == ord('p'):
       index = index -1 
       if index < 0:
           index = N - 1
       next
    # q = Quit
    if key == ord('q'):
       break
    # space = toggle between underscore and semicolon
    if key == ord(' '):
       if JPEG[offsets[index]] == ord('_'):
           print(f'{index}/{N}: Toggling to ;')
           JPEG[offsets[index]] = ord(';')
       else:
           print(f'{index}/{N}: Toggling to _')
           JPEG[offsets[index]] = ord('_')
       next
```

---

**Note**: Toggling some bytes between `'_'` and `';'` results in illegal images and error messages from `cv2.imdecode()` and/or `cv2.imshow()`. Ideally you would wrap these inside a `try/except` and back out the last change if they occur. I didn't do that, yet.

**Note**: I didn't implement `save` function, it is just something like `open('corrected.jpg', 'wb').write(JPEG)`